# Word or phrase for something that turns out great but wasn't intended as such

Tags: idioms, translation

I'm translating a German press release about a product that became a great tool/solution, but it had never been intended to be developed like that in the first place. It more or less happened by accident.<sup>*</sup>

I came up with this translation:

> Few developments that turn out to be good have been intended and meticulously planned from the start.

This is a rather literal translation, but it sounds quite awkward. Is there any idiom for something that turns out better than expected and wasn't planned as such?

<sub>* For reference, in German, it's “Nicht alle guten Entwicklungen waren von Anfang an beabsichtigt und penibel geplant. Auch die Initialzündung für XXX geschah mehr oder minder zufällig.”</sub>

Comment: The single word request is a duplicate, covered at [an adjective for an inconspicuous event that later leads to great things](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274951/an-adjective-for-an-inconspicuous-event-that-later-lead-to-great-things/274979#274979)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the well known proverb

*Mighty oaks from little acorns grow.*

> Proverb
>
> **Mighty oaks from little acorns grow**
>
> Something great can come from a modest beginning.
>
> - Don't give up on the project –  mighty oaks from little acorns grow!

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mighty_oaks_from_little_acorns_grow)]

This is probably more often used as an encouragement than an observation.

I prefer the W C Fields adaptation;

'*From the little acorn* ...

*the mighty oak did grow*.'

Comment: I am afraid this sounds too poetic in that context (technical press release), but I like the description "something great can come from a modest beginning."

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for a word since the title says that. I remember having read somewhere Charles Goodyear's accidental discovery of vulcanization being described as **serendipity.** I believe that should apply to the context you've provided as well:

> The faculty of making fortunate discoveries by accident.

> The fact or occurrence of such discoveries.

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: Actually the title says "word or phrase", so it doesn't have to be a single word. Could you perhaps show me how you'd use that word in the particular context?

Comment: Yes, I think this is ideal. I've always associated it with Goodyear's discovery of the vulcanisation of rubber, Fleming's discovery of the antibacterial properties of penicillin. Though I don't believe that these were pure 'chance'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth— Thanks a lot. An imprimatur from someone of your caliber definitely means a lot!!

Comment: It's nice to have someone use the word 'caliber' rather than 'bore'.

Comment: In all honesty I meant it as a compliment, Sir! :)